# How to remove redundant file open operation in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-csv

I made a ruby program to copy content of one CSV file to a new CSV file.

This is my code -

```
require 'csv'
class CopyFile
  def self.create_duplicate_file(file_name)

    CSV.open(file_name, "wb") do |output_row|
      output_row << CSV.open('input.csv', 'r') { |csv| csv.first }
      CSV.foreach('input.csv', headers: true) do |row|
      output_row << row
      end
    end
  end
end

puts "Insert duplicate file name"
file_name = gets.chomp
file_name = file_name+".csv"
CopyFile.create_duplicate_file(file_name)

puts "\nDuplicate File Created."
```

I am opening the input.csv file twice, one to copy headers and then to copy content.

I want to optimise my code. So is there a way to optimise it further?

Comment: Why don't you just copy the whole file?

Answer (score -1):

Just use the `cp` [method](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp):
`FileUtils.cp(src, destination, options)`, no need to reinvent the wheel, like this:

```
class CopyFile
  def self.create_duplicate_file(file_name)
    FileUtils.cp('input.csv',file_name)
  end
end
```

or better yet:

```
file_name = gets.chomp
file_name = file_name+".csv"
FileUtils.cp('input.csv', file_name)
```

Comment: Module methods can not be arbitrary called without explicit module specification. `FileUtils.cp` would work, `cp` evidently won’t.